# Can the product of two positive floats be negative?

Tags: floating-point

When looking at a piece of code recently, I came across a line that had me thinking:

```
if a*b > 0:
  # do stuff
```

It should be assumed that `a` and `b` are floats.

> Question:
>   Is it possible that there exist (very small, positive, and likely close to ~eps_mach) values of `a` and `b` such that their product is negative?  If not, could it be that we have `a*b==0` with neither `a==0` nor `b==0`.

To not be a complete slouch, here are my thoughts:

1. No, it is possible since in FP arithmetic the product is likely defined in such a way that the sign bits of `a` and `b` determine the sign bit of `a*b`.  Thus at some base-level the computation runs "Note sign bit of `a` is positive.  Note sign bit of `b` is positive.  Set sign bit of `a*b` to positive."  I imagine this convention is specified and universally classified *somewhere* provided it exists.
2. The `a*b==0` with `a!=0` and `b!=0` seems certainly possible.
3. The answer will be computer-dependent and language-dependent.

This leads me to a sub-question:

> Question:
>   Would it be safer to implement the code as below?  If it is not safer, then how should it be done?

```
if (a>0 and b>0) or (a<0 and b<0):
  # do stuff
```

Comment: @old_timer Why would you expect a NaN rather than positive infinity?

Comment: @old_timer IEEE754 calls for infinity, as does the Java Language Specification. Other languages may do something weird, but I would generally expect infinity. It makes a difference because NaN>0, like all NaN comparisons, is false.

Comment: Ill delete my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the IEEE-754 standard (with default rounding mode), the result of any floating point operation (blah blah transcendentals) is rounded to the nearest representable number. The product of any two positive numbers is positive, so worst case, the closest representable number is zero. There is no way for the closest representable number to be negative.

Your proposed alternative code is correct. For languages with a `sgn`/`signum` function, you can also do something like `if sgn(a)*sgn(b) > 0`.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The two pieces of code are not equivalent, because the product of two positive but tiny numbers can indeed be zero.

Which is correct depends on what the test is really about.

If subsequent code needs the product to be strictly positive, you need the `a*b > 0` form, not tests on the individual values.

If each value needs to be strictly positive, test for that.

The test you are proposing is correct if the requirement is that they are both non-zero and have the same sign.

Here is a Java program that tests some of the cases, including both tiny but strictly positive:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    testit(Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MIN_VALUE);
    testit(-Double.MIN_VALUE, -Double.MIN_VALUE);
    testit(1e-320, 1e-320);
    testit(1e300, 1e300);
  }

  public static void testit(double a, double b) {
    System.out.println("a="+a+" b="+b);
    System.out.println("a*b > 0 " + (a * b > 0));
    System.out.println("(a>0 && b>0) " + (a > 0 && b > 0));
    System.out.println("(a<0 && b<0) " + (a < 0 && b < 0));
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes.  A hiccup in my question.  The initial test I listed was a "shortcut" to determine if exactly one of a or b is negative.  It crossed my mind as being dangerous which has been confirmed now.